# Bootstrap modal "shown.bs.modal" does not alter my checkbox inside the modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I have check boxes that need to be loaded when my page loads. It will look from the dictionary provided from the DjangoTemplate and check some check boxes.

I tried using `"shown.bs.modal"` it executes the codes, but later I found out that my check boxes are set back to its default un-checked.

I found out that using `setInterval()` to set the check boxes is working as what I want. It seems after the modal loads it takes 1 - 2 seconds before the check boxes actually checked. So, something definitely happen after `"shown.bs.modal"` that reset back my check boxes to un-checked.

My solution so far is to use `setTimeout()` after `"shown.bs.modal"` to check the check boxes. But I am still wondering what is the cause.

```
/*
Used to detect if modal page button is triggered or not. These codes does
not set the check boxes checked.
*/
$("#sample").on("shown.bs.modal", function(event) {
  for (var i = 0; i < index_checkbox.length; i ++) {
    console.log("something is actually happened here");
    $("#checkbox-" + index_checkbox).prop("checked", true);
    console.log("the value of `prop('checked')` is changed");
    console.log("but later it goes back to `false`");
  }
}).modal("show");

// These codes checked the check boxes after 1 - 2 seconds.
window.setInterval(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < index_checkbox.length; i ++) {
    $("#checkbox-" + index_checkbox).prop("checked", true);
  }
}, 1000);

// The checkbox generated from DjangoTemplate.
<input id="checkbox-{{ teacher.id }}" type="checkbox" name="teacher"
    value="{{ teacher.id }}"
    ng-model="teacher_checkbox[{{ forloop.counter0 }}]" />
```

EDIT: Actually, setting the `setInterval()` to `100` millisecond also works. But if possible I want to not use `setInterval()`.

EDIT: Interval of `0` also works. I am confused....

Comment: Do you have the `$("#sample").on("shown.bs.modal", ...` inside of a `$(document).ready( funtion(){ ...` or `$(function() { ...`?

Comment: O yes that is the solution! Just put below I will mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap any bootstrap events, like `'shown.bs.whatever'` in either a

```
$(document).ready( function()

});
```

or

```
$(function(){

});
```